# How to fix npm run dev and npm run watch

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-8

Hi I have recently installed windows 10 and installed new versions of Laravel installer and npm and node

previously whenever I run npm dev or npm run watch never had any issues, after having installed new node, npm, and Laravel installer I am getting the following options

on NPM RUN DEV never used to get that I need to install webpack-cli this time I did I installed it and when I ran npm run dev I am getting the following errors

[image: el]

[image]

Which one of the options should i choose?

Comment: That's not an error, that looks like the usage (`--help`) for Webpack. Scroll up to see if there's an actual error message.

Comment: Thanks, @AKX added the error screen but in the past, I never used to get this screen either

Comment: You may have upgraded your webpack/webpack-cli to a version that's no longer compatible with your `"scripts"` entries.

Comment: a novice here how would I know that which version of the webpack do I need

Comment: Since you're using Laravel/Laravel Mix, that information would probably be in the Laravel documentation.

Comment: @AKX same project which was running previously now showing me this screen never encounter any of that sort of issue before